# Изменение вывода даты, бытрикс

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, если использовать функцию TIMESTAMP_X, т она выводит мне дату с точностью до секунд, а как быть если мне нужно вывести все кроме секунд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком случае нужно форматировать дату и время по такому формату:

```
print (new \Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime($arItem['TIMESTAMP_X']))->format('d.m.Y, H:i');
```

Запятую можно убрать, если не нужна.